# add custom data with quote item magento

Tags: magento

I need a custom field in cart in with I can display uploaded file link. I am uploading file at product view page and handling this in observer. although I have change product custom price and quantity in observer and it working fine. Now further I want to show uploaded file link with each item in cart and want this link in order also.

I am a bigginger and not sure about flow that how would I achieve this. Can any one help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create one table with two columns ( quote ID , filename ) i think for this option use simple jquery file upload in checkout file. just do one thing once you allow user to upload file then upload file on server and add quote ID and filename in custom table then in backend just display that file link in order detail page.
according to me best option.
no need to touch magento tables because once you update magento version this can create problem.
Thanks